# Points left out when nearby in scipy.spatial.Delaunay

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, delaunay

I am noticing an unexplained behaviour when comparing scipy's (0.9.0) and matplotlib's (1.0.1) Delaunay triangulation routines. My points are UTM coordinates stored in `numpy.array([[easting, northing], [easting, northing], [easting, northing]])`. Scipy's edges are missing some of my points, while matplotlib's are all there. Is there a fix, or am I doing something wrong?

```
import scipy
import numpy
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.delaunay


def delaunay_edges(points):
    d = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points)
    s = d.vertices
    return numpy.vstack((s[:,:2], s[:,1:], s[:,::-2]))


def delaunay_edges_matplotlib(points):
        cens, edges, tri, neig = matplotlib.delaunay.delaunay(points[:,0], points[:,1])
        return edges


points = numpy.array([[500000.25, 6220000.25],[500000.5, 6220000.5],[500001.0, 6220001.0],[500002.0, 6220003.0],[500003.0, 6220005.0]])

edges1 = delaunay_edges(points)
edges2 = delaunay_edges_matplotlib(points)

numpy.unique(edges1).shape # Some points missing, presumably nearby ones
numpy.unique(edges2).shape # Includes all points
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior of `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` might be connected with the impresicion of the floating point arithmetic.

As you may know, `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` uses C `qhull` library to calculate Delaunay triangulation. `Qhull`, in its turn, is the implementation of [`Quickhull` algorithm](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/quickhull.html), which is in details described by the authors in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.405&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper (1). You as well may know that floating-point arithmetic used in computers is carried out using IEEE 754 standard (you can read about it in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), for instance). According to the standard, each finite number is most simply described by three integers: `s`= a sign (zero or one), `c`= a significand (or 'coefficient'), `q`= an exponent. The number of bits used to represent these integers varies with data type. So, it's obvious, that the density of floating point number distribution on nummerical axis is not constant - the greater numbers, the more loosely they are distributed. It can be seen even with Google calculator - you can subtract 3333333333333333 from 3333333333333334 and [get 0](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=3333333333333334%20-%203333333333333333). That happens because 3333333333333333 and 3333333333333334 both are rounded to the same floating point number.

Now, knowing about rounding errors, we might want to read chapter 4 of the paper (1), entitled *Copying with impresicion*. In this chapter, an algorithm of dealing with rounding errors is described:

```
Quickhull partitions a point and determines its horizon facets by computing 
whether the point is above or below a hyperplane. We have assumed that 
computations return consistent results ... With floating-point arithmetic, we 
cannot prevent errors from occurring, but we can repair the damage after 
processing a point. We use brute force: if adjacent facets are nonconvex, one of 
the facets is merged into a neighbor. Quickhull merges the facet that minimizes 
the maximum distance of a vertex to the neighbor.
```

So that's what might happens - `Quickhull` cannot distinguish between 2 nearby points, so it merges two facets, thus successfully eliminating one of them. To eliminate these errors, you can, for instance, try to move your coordinate origin:

```
co = points[0]
points = points - co

edges1 = delaunay_edges(points)
edges2 = delaunay_edges_matplotlib(points)

print numpy.unique(edges1) 
>>> [0 1 2 3 4]
print numpy.unique(edges2)
>>> [0 1 2 3 4]
```

This moves computations to the region where floating point numbers are reasonably dense.